# Modifying an immutable/protected variable of a subclass in a superclass method

Tags: matlab, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to modify an immutable/protected property of a subclass, using a superclass method or an external utility function (I'm trying to use this function in the subclass's constructor, of course).

Example (of what I would like to do):

```
classdef Sup
  methods
    function self = setProperties(self, varargin)
      % This method sets the properties of the object
      % the input arguments come in the form 'propname1', val1, 'propname2', val2, ...
      ...
    end % setProperties
  end % methods
end % classdef Sup


classdef sub < Sup
  properties (SetAccess = immutable)
    prop1
    prop2
    prop3
  end % properties
  methods
    function self = sub(varargin)
      % constructor
      self = setProperties(self, varargin)
    end % sub
  end % methods
end % classdef sub


>> SomeObj = sub('prop1', 1, 'prop2', 10, 'prop3', 100);
```

This code doesn't work, I get the error message 'You cannot set the read-only property 'prop1' of sub.'

I'm OK with setting sub's properties to be protected, but I wouldn't want them to be public. I'm also OK with the idea that setProperties would be an external utility function (not defined in the superclass), but then again, I'm not able to use setProperties in the constructor of sub.

Would appreciate your help on that.
Thank you,

Avihay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to, you could set the `SetAccess` attribute of `sub` to `?Sup` - in other words saying that they can only be set by the class `Sup`.

That seems to do what you're directly asking for - however, I should say that this seems like an unusual pattern to be implementing. I wonder whether a better suggestion might be to examine why you're finding a need to do this, and perhaps redesign your class relationships.

Edit:

If what you need is a general method of conveniently setting properties in a constructor, you could try inheriting your class from the built-in class `hgsetget`. For example,

```
classdef sub < hgsetget
    properties (SetAccess = immutable)
    prop1
    prop2
    prop3
  end % properties
  methods
    function self = sub(varargin)
      set(self,varargin{:})
    end
  end
end
```

`hgsetget` gives you built-in methods `set` (and `get`) that can be used with the syntax `set(obj, 'myprop', myval, 'myprop2', myval2)` and similar (like MATLAB Handle Graphics objects, hence the `hg` in `hgsetget`).

That might be more convenient for you. Note, though, that `hgsetget` is itself a subclass of `handle`, so you will have to be comfortable with your classes being `handle` objects. However, if you're considering `immutable` properties, then you're probably OK with that already.

Edit 2:

Another approach, which would work with value objects, might be the following:

```
classdef sub
  properties (SetAccess = immutable)
    prop1
    prop2
    prop3
  end % properties
  methods
    function self = sub(varargin)
      % constructor
      props = varargin(1:2:end-1);
      vals = varargin(2:2:end);
      for i = 1:numel(props)
          self.(props{i}) = vals{i};
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you could make use of `inputParser` within the constructor, to give you a more flexible range of syntaxes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Using `?Sup` in the `SetAccess` does work, but I don't like it so much, as you might have many `properties...end` blocks in your code. What I'm really trying to do, is defining a general superclass to be used with many subclasses that I generate. I want `setProperties` to be available to all of those subclasses, but then I want to have some `protected` properties.

Comment: Thanks again, Sam, this approach is indeed very interesting. I actually wasn't intending to use a `handle` object, as most of the code that I'm working on already uses `value` objects (unfortunately)... Do you know of any way to do that for `value` objects? By the way, if you have any suggestions for a different design that might solve my problem, it would be great as well.

Comment: There's another try in my edit. This is basically a very simple reimplementation of something similar to what `hgsetget` does.

Comment: That's more or less what I'm doing now, I wanted to get rid of the verbosity :) Anyway, thank you very much! I would have voted up your answer, but I don't have enough reputation...